# How to convert WebBrowser To Local Image with Codename One?

Tags: java, cross-platform, codenameone

I am using Codename One.

In my program I generate html code dynamically. I would like to grab a screenshot of the web browser view so I can send the screenshot as an image to users.

I've tried calling `browserComponent.paint(Graphics)` to draw this onto a mutable image but this resulted in a blank image. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Some more details. An example of the generated HTML would make the question more clear.

Comment: Do you want to create an image of the rendered html-code like a browser would do, or an image of the HTML-code as a listing?

Comment: yes I want to create an html with custom design and at the end I want to convert the final result from html to image @MrSmith42

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) And the perfect question And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) SO is not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service Here at SO we fix your attempts, we do not code things for you

Comment: I don't want anyone to write the code [ I am asking the experts in codename one if there are any reference or possibility to do what I want ]

Thanks ,

Comment: I edited this with a sample and nominated for reopening. I can answer this already though, you can't. HTML is rendered natively in the OS as a peer component see: http://www.codenameone.com/blog/understanding-peer-native-components-why-codename-one-is-so-portable.html unfortunately peer components are rendered separately so you can't grab a screenshot of them. You can draw anything you want onto an Image using mutable images but you can't grab the image of an arbitrary peer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't grab a screenshot of a peer component.

HTML is rendered natively in the OS as a `PeerComponent` see this [blog post explaining peer components](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/understanding-peer-native-components-why-codename-one-is-so-portable.html). Unfortunately peer components are rendered separately so you can't grab a screenshot of a peer.

You can draw anything you want onto an Image using mutable images but you can't grab the image of an arbitrary peer. Check out our [graphics section](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/graphics.html) in the developer guide to see how one draws on an image.